# Using a search engine (like Algolia or Typesense) as a primary data source

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, algolia, typesense

I have been developing apps that use Firestore as a primary data store and Typesense for full-text search.  Some collections are completely duplicated and synced between the databases.

Is there a reason why I should not use Typesense as the SOLE data collection and avoid keeping a collection of the data in Firestore?

What are the downsides of using a search engine as a primary datastore?  Expense? Scalability?

Comment: We do the same with Firestore and ElasticSearch to allow full text search among many other search benefits. We keep both databases because many features on the client depend on the auto update we get from using Firestore client libraries. So, for some cases we show "lists screens" from Elastic (allowing full text search and complex queries), and "detail screens" from Firestore which update in real-time. We also trigger a list update on the client after we know Elastic has been updated, depending on the case. I know it's kind of an overkill but our users love the result.

Comment: https://discourse.algolia.com/t/algolia-as-a-datastore/287/2

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a reason why I should not use Typesense as the SOLE data collection and avoid keeping a collection of the data in Firestore?

[Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure), [scalability](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-scalable-apps-with-cloud-firestore), [offline data persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline), and interoperability with all the other [Firebase products](https://firebase.google.com/products-build). Besides that, I think that the following resource might also help:

- [How to filter Firestore data cheaper?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444)

Comment: Hey Paul. Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

That depend of your business and your process to input datas in your system.

If you need a specific backend, firebase cloud-function coupled with algolia, is a good option. with `npm algoliasearch`

As database with firebase no cost, (only read and write does),so is not a big deal to keep data in Firebase and perform search engine and filters UI with algolia